Aalen Johansen - absolute risks and confidence intervals
In case of a present competing risk situation, one can use the AJ estimator for the cumulative incidence function (CIF).
In R, implementation of the AJ is straightforward using survfit{survival} with events 0,1,2.
When inspecting the absolute risk at time 20, R also calculates a confidence interval $lower and $upper such as:



time
cif
cif_lower
cif_upper




20
0.0175
0.0097
0.0314



Thus, at time 20, 1,75% suffered the event (CI 0.97% - 3.14%)
Questions:

What kind of confidence interval is that?
Does the AJ estimator needs a specific confidence interval?
Does this specific confidence interval needs to be further adjusted after using matching/ weighting?



The type of confidence interval is whatever was specified in the conf.type argument to survfit(). The default, according to the manual page, is "log".

Therneau and Grambsch specificaly recommend the log transform for cumulative hazards, but continue (page 17): "Actually, as long as one avoids the "plain" intervals, all of the options work well."

The survfit() function directly handles weights as an argument in the function call. If you specified them appropriately they will be taken into account in the calculations.


